# marker become invisible when line chart negative values in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, linechart

marker of negative value become invisible in line chart type in highcharts

My fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/TnTsr/542/

i have tried to change plot options but it seems like that there is no error in plot options.

Advance thanks

```
{
    "chart": {
    "renderTo": "container",
    "reportCode": "container",
    "defaultSeriesType": "line",
    "events": {

    }
  },
  "title": {
    "text": null,
    "style": {
      "fontSize": "11px",
      "fontFamily": "Open Sans , sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": "normal"
    }
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": null,
    "style": {
      "fontSize": "11px",
      "fontFamily": "Open Sans , sans-serif",
      "fontWeight": "normal"
    }
  },
  "legend": {
    "floating": false,
    "enabled": false,
    "itemStyle": {
      "fontSize": "9px"
    },
    "verticalAlign": "bottom",
    "layout": "horizontal",
    "align": "center",
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "symbolWidth": 9
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": [
      "Glendale Adventist ",
      "Simi Valley ",
      "Feather River ",
      "St Helena (Clearlake)",
      "White Memorial ",
      "Frank R Howard Memorial ",
      "San Joaquin Comm ",
      "St Helena ",
      "Sonora Reg ",
      "Ukiah Valley ",
      "Central Valley General"
    ],
    "categoriesFullName": [
      ""
    ],
    "enabledCategoryAbbreviation": false,
    "title": {
      "text": "",
      "style": {
        "fontSize": "12px",
        "fontFamily": "Open Sans , sans-serif",
        "color": "black",
        "fontWeight": "normal"
      }
    },
    "labels": {
      "enabled": true,
      "style": {
        "fontSize": "10px",
        "fontFamily": "Open Sans , sans-serif",
        "fontWeight": "normal"
      },
      "rotation": 315,
      "align": "right"
    }
  },
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "labels": {
        "style": {
          "fontSize": "12px",
          "fontFamily": "Open Sans , sans-serif",
          "fontWeight": "normal"
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "text": "CS-ALOS GAP",
        "tooltip": "At DRG Level CS-ALOS Gap = (Facility CS-ALOS) -(Benchmark CS-ALOS). At Any Level above DRG CS-ALOS Gap = (Gap Days)/Discharges",
        "style": {
          "fontSize": "12px",
          "fontFamily": "Open Sans , sans-serif",
          "color": "#3E576F",
          "fontWeight": "normal"
        }
      },
      "opposite": false,
      "plotLines": [

      ],
      "plotBands": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "tooltip": {
    "shared": false,
    "borderWidth": "0",
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    "style": {
      "line-height": "18px",
      "fontSize": "10px",
      "fontFamily": "Open Sans , sans-serif",
      "color": "#1A5488",
      "padding": "8px"
    },
    "Color": "#1A5488",
    "borderRadius": "3",
    "shadow": "false",
    "borderColor": "rgba(48,132,201,1)",
    "padding": "5",
    "font-family": "arial",
    "font-size": "10",
    "z-index": "10"
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "column": {
      "dataLabels": {

      },
      "pointPadding": "0.01",
      "groupPadding": "0.09",
      "borderColor": "black",
      "borderWidth": 1,
      "shadow": false
    },
    "bar": {
      "dataLabels": {

      },
      "pointPadding": "0.01",
      "groupPadding": "0.09",
      "borderColor": "black",
      "borderWidth": 1,
      "shadow": false
    },
    "scatter": {
      "marker": {
        "radius": 9
      }
    },
    "pie": {
      "allowPointSelect": true,
      "cursor": "pointer",
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": true,
        "color": "#000000",
        "connectorColor": "#000000"
      }
    },
    "series": {
      "groupPadding": "0.04"
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "Hospitals",
      "type": "line",
      "yAxis": 0,
      "index": 0,
      "isAdditionalYAxisSeries": false,
      "color": "#0833ff",
      "data": [
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": 1.12,
          "dataElementValue": "Glendale Adventist ",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        },
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": 0.99,
          "dataElementValue": "Simi Valley ",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        },
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": 0.71,
          "dataElementValue": "Feather River ",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        },
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": 0.7,
          "dataElementValue": "St Helena (Clearlake)",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        },
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": 0.68,
          "dataElementValue": "White Memorial ",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        },
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": 0.49,
          "dataElementValue": "Frank R Howard Memorial ",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        },
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": 0.37,
          "dataElementValue": "San Joaquin Comm ",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        },
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": 0.36,
          "dataElementValue": "St Helena ",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        },
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": -0.05,
          "dataElementValue": "Sonora Reg ",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        },
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": -0.23,
          "dataElementValue": "Ukiah Valley ",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        },
        {
          "customTooltip": [

          ],
          "y": -0.3,
          "dataElementValue": "Central Valley General",
          "dataElementName": "Hospitals",
          "columnStacking": false,
          "color": "#0833ff",
          "isPointColor": true,
          "isSeriesColor": true,
          "colorIndex": "0"
        }
      ],
      "colorIndex": "0"
    }
  ],
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known bug, already resolved on `master` version: http://jsfiddle.net/TnTsr/543/

Comment: Thanks, but i have already fixed that, the issue was in data objects that I was assigning each point a color rather than assigning color to points i just assign color to series. the fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/TnTsr/545/

Comment: Yes, that's true, however color for each point should work also :) As is on master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but i have already fixed that, the issue was in data objects that I was assigning each point a color rather than assigning color to points i just assign color to series. the fiddle is : jsfiddle.net/TnTsr/545 –